# vector variable inside for loop

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I have defined an empty vector variable inside the loop for the test case, after execution of each test case I expect the vector will go empty, but it is storing the previous result of the earlier test cases as well please help thanks a lot.

My problem statement is [this.](https://www.codechef.com/START5C/problems/TOTCRT) which takes input as:

> - The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
> - The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
> - N lines follow. For each valid i, the i-th of these lines contains a string S<sub>3,i</sub> followed by a space and an integer
>   C<sub>3,i</sub> — the problem code and the number of correct solutions
>   on the i-th problem in the third division.
> - N more lines follow. For each valid i, the i-th of these lines contains a string S<sub>2,I</sub> followed by a space and an integer
>   C<sub>2,i</sub> — the problem code and the number of correct solutions
>   on the i-th problem in the second division.
> - Finally, N more lines follow. For each valid i, the i-th of these lines contains a string S<sub>1,i</sub> followed by a space and an
>   integer C<sub>1,i</sub> — the problem code and the number of correct
>   solutions on the i-th problem in the first division.

GOAL:
Codechef challenges have three divisions. In one challenge, there are N problems in each division, but some problems may be shared among multiple divisions. Each problem is uniquely identified by a code — a string containing only uppercase English letters. Each participant can only submit in one of the divisions.

Chef wants to find the number of correct solutions, in total among all 3 divisions, for each problem. Given a list of N problem codes with the numbers of correct solutions for each problem in each division, find the total number of correct solutions for each problem and sort them in non-decreasing order.

My code takes `input` as:

```
3
1
A 1
B 2
C 3
2
AA 1
AB 1
AB 1
AC 1
AC 1
AD 1
1
Z 100
Z 100
Z 100
```

The expected `output` is:

```
1 2 3
1 1 2 2
300
```

But my output has errors:

```
1 2 3 
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 300
```

My code for above problem is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    map<string,int>m;
    int t,n,c_1;
    string s_1;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        cin>>n;
        for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                cin>>s_1;
                cin>>c_1;
                m[s_1]+=c_1;
            }
        }
        vector<int>v;
        for(auto x :m){
            v.push_back(x.second);
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        for(auto y: v){
            cout<<y<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n" ;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: *but it is storing the previous result of the earlier test cases* -- The easiest solution -- create a function called `test()` and call that function instead of stuffing everything inside of `main`.  Then everything is local to `test()` and will not pollute other test cases.

Comment: @Rajakr What is the magic number 3 doing here for(int k=0;k<3;k++){?! The code does not make a sense and the question should be closed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sir 3 is used as it is taking input 3 times n, mentioned in the link, should I write complete question as well?

Comment: @Rajakr You should provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i have written the complete code and also adding input format of question

Comment: @Rajakr -- `map<string,int>m;` -- You are using the same map on multiple test cases.  Is that your goal?  If not, then look at my first comment.

Comment: yes sir i have no option other than using same map

Comment: @Rajakr -- That doesn't make sense.  If each test case is independent of each other, then *why* are you using the same map, the map that will have junk in it from a previous test case?  It should be obvious to you that the map is not "clean" when a new test case is run.

Comment: this is goal: Codechef challenges have three divisions. In one challenge, there are N problems in each division, but some problems may be shared among multiple divisions. Each problem is uniquely identified by a code — a string containing only uppercase English letters. Each participant can only submit in one of the divisions.

Chef wants to find the number of correct solutions, in total among all 3 divisions, for each problem. Given a list of N problem codes with the numbers of correct solutions for each problem in each division, find the total number of correct solutions for each problem

Comment: @Rajakr If it is a complete program then one more what is the magic number 3 doing in the program?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sir i told it is required to solve the problem,question has mentioned it which I have edited now, please have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *vector* (`v`) is being reset (to empty) on each run of the outer `for` loop but your *map* (`m`) isn't. That is keeping its content each time, and your new inputs are being appended to it. Thus, your `for (auto x : m) {` appends the data from each previous loop to your (initially empty) vector.

Move the declaration of `map<string, int>m;` to *inside* that outer loop to fix your problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using std::cin, std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::vector;
using std::sort;

int main()
{
    int t, n, c_1;
    string s_1;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        map<string, int>m; // Move the map to here, so it's created afresh for each loop.
        cin >> n;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cin >> s_1;
                cin >> c_1;
                m[s_1] += c_1;
            }
        }
        vector<int>v;
        for (auto x : m) {
            v.push_back(x.second);
        }
        sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        for (auto y : v) {
            cout << y << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the same map each time and just reset (clear) it on each run of the outer loop, by adding a `m.clear();` as the first line inside that loop.